# WooCommerce: Add to Cart Button with Quantity - outside WooCommerce Loop

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

In addition to the WooCommerce product home page, I coded a second page template (with the wordpress page template function https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-templates/) that shows the woocommerce products in another schema.

... we call it „speed buy“, there is no informations about the products, just a list with title, price and the add to cart button.

My problem is, that we want to have not the normal add to cart button, but the add to cart button with quantity. Actually we call the add to cart button with

```
<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item' ); ?>
```

But this is the normal one without quantity.. any ideas?

Edit: We display the products on the page-template with a custom loop / WP_Query.

Comment: By default the woocommerce shop page and other archives pages doesn't have any quantity field… To embed it in shop page there is this official snippet code: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/override-loop-template-and-show-quantities-next-to-add-to-cart-buttons/

Comment: Awesome! This is what I am looking for, thank you!